# Google Sheets SUMIF exclude rows that has scpecific value in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have simple sheet with two columns:

| amount | reserved |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |
| -- | -- |
| **Total not reserved:** | =SUMIF(A2:A6, B3&"<>1") ***What formula to use here?*** |

What kind of formula should I write to exclude all rows that has `reserved = 1`? So in this example formula should return *30*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set SUMIF with one range that has the desired condition, and then you you specify the range you actually want to sum:

> =SUMIF(B2:b6,0,A2:A6)

Comment: You can also use "<>1" as a condition